# Xamarin - preventing memory leaks in ViewHolder & Adapter pattern

Tags: c#, android, memory-leaks, xamarin, xamarin.android

We are managing references in our ViewHolder in a following way:

```
public class MusicListViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object, IImageLoadingListener, View.IOnClickListener
    {
        public static readonly float COVER_ART_THUMB_SIZE_PX = 90;

        public delegate void OptionSelectedDelegate(object item);
        public delegate void PlayPauseClickDelegate(object item);

        private TextView m_title;
        private TextView m_subtitle;
        private TextView m_infoRow;
        private ImageView m_art;
        private ImageView m_downloadState;
        private RelativeLayout m_optionRelativeLayout;
        private ImageView m_optionImageView;
```

The worry I am having is that this looks a little like as a memory leak as we do not dispose the referenced TextViews and ImageViews anywhere. As I learnt when working with Xamarin everything should be properly disposed.

Are these references somehow magically destroyed by the adapter? Does this actually leak? The only suitable method to override that I found was:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
```

Should I call `m_title.Dispose()` etc. in the override of `protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)`? Or is there anything else to this that I am missing?

Comment: "Does this actually leak?". Have you tried profiling it?

Comment: Typically no, the only effective way I've seen to get rid of references whether weak or strong are to null objects which gets rid of the reference.  But @Cheesebaron's point is valid Profile the project first.

Comment: @Jakub : Did you solve you issue? Please help me to solve mine. I'm facing same issue and actually I don't get the profiler usage.

Comment: @SagarPanwala I actually haven't made the effort to use profiler to debug this as this was pure theoretical question. When I have a bit of time i will do that. But so far it doesn't seem to leak but if it does it doesn't cause any big leaks.

Comment: @JakubHolovsky : Please mention your outcome when you will do it , so it will help dev like me. I have very serious problem with memory in my many app. But don't know how to solve that problem.

Comment: @SagarPanwala It really depends on many things in your app. Ideally you should be disposing anything that touches Java. Also make sure you are properly disposing bitmaps. Another thing to look at is that if you are not storing somewhere list of fragments which you then don't dispose or remove from. It's a complex thing these memory leaks and it's hard to just point out one thing.

Comment: @JakubHolovsky : Thanks, but I'm not using bitmap directly. I'm using Picasso or Universal Image Loader to load images and I have a listview and viewpager as item (with 5 images each). OOM occures when I just scroll the listview.

Comment: @SagarPanwala well, we are using Universal Image Loader too, but it only loads Images however you need to take care of disposing them.

Comment: @JakubHolovsky Thank for quick and consistent response. How can I dispose images in adapter? How to unbind event in adapter?

Comment: @SagarPanwala are you handling fragments in your adapter? or what kind of views is it? Could you maybe post your code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JakubHolovsky : Thanks I will create a sample from my code and I will make sure that adapter code is same. Yes We are using fragments because we have viewpager (5- images) as a listitems.

Comment: I recommend reading this thread: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/3057/on-which-object-and-when-we-have-to-use-dispose